# Erro de leitura XML da Nota Fiscal Eletrônica NFE

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Gente eu usei o aplicativo XSD do windows para gerar classes para NFE, ele funcionou 100%, agora preciso utilizar essas classes para preencher com dados das notas ficais que serão importados, estou fazendo isso:

```
TNFe nfe = null;
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TNFe));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Arquivos\XML_7446_1.xml", FileMode.Open);
nfe = (TNFe)xmls.Deserialize(fs);
```

TNFe é a classe que é gerada pelo XSD, li aqui em outro tópico que usar a primeira tag como `classe` para preencher por esse procedimento acima.
Se alguém puder me ajudar, ele da um erro assim:

> "Erro no documento XML (1,2)"

a primeira linha da nota é assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10"><NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe31150608405781000106550010000631581000560951">
```

Comment: Nunca usei, mais uma vez um amigo estava com esse problema e era o XML dele que estava errado e gerava esse erro.

Comment: Como esta sua classe TNFe? e o arquivo xml?

Comment: Esse erro é do xml linha 1 posição 2.

Comment: Coloque o arquivo XML aqui

Comment: já editei com os dados, estou aprendendo a usar aqui